# How to merge two files based on the matching of one column?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, pattern-matching

I have two files, `B.csv`:

```
1,AD
2,AB
3,AC
5,AF
7,AE
```

and `C.csv`:

```
1,x
3,z
5,y
```

How do I get this output:

```
1,AD,x
2,AB,
3,AC,z
5,AF,y
7,AE,
```

by matching the common column 1 in both of the files?

Comment: What should be output for a key that exists in B but not C and vice-versa? Include those cases in your example.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` without dis-ordering lines of the original files, but require to loading the first file into the memory and you would need to care to don't run on big file that cannot fit into your memory.

```
awk 'BEGIN        { FS=OFS="," }
     NR==FNR      { hold[$1]=$2; next }
{ print $0, hold[$1] }' fileC fileB
```

---

for such a case when there was a key that exist in fileC but not in fileB, and to print those are in fileC as well, do;

```
awk 'BEGIN        { FS=OFS="," }
     NR==FNR      { hold[$1]=$2; next }
{ print $0, hold[$1]; delete hold[$1] }

END{ for(x in hold) print x, hold[x] }' fileC fileB
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join)

```bsh
join -t, -a1  B.csv C.csv
```

The `-a1` means left outer join (i.e show lines from file1 that are not in file2)

If commas at the end of unpaired lines *really* matter

```bsh
(join -t, B.csv C.csv ; join -t, -v1 B.csv C.csv | perl -pe "s/$/,/" ) | sort
```

Comment: Note that you will need to sort the files first if they are not already sorted.

Comment: @Freddy if you really want comma's at the end of unpaired fields, write a perl script or similar. You can use

`(join -t, a.csv b.csv ; join -t, -v1 a.csv b.csv | perl -pe "s/$/,/" ) | sort`


though it's not something I'd recommend

Comment: @Grynn I don't care, I'm just nitpicking :)

Comment: You can get the commas with `join -t, -a1 -o 0,1.2,2.2 -e ""  B.csv C.csv` -- it's annoying that all the output fields must be specified